# Experience Editor Error - ExperienceEditor.getPageEditingWindow is not a function

Tags: experience-editor

When I try to use the experience editor I get an error that causes the loading sign to just keep spinning and it also prevents the Ribbon menu at the top from displaying.

[image: Javascript error sitecore experience editor]

Heres where the error is occuring in the "LargeDropDownButton.js" file
[image]

Comment: Have you changed something recently that could have caused this? Added a new ribbon button, changed security on ribbon items, etc.

Comment: Have you fixed that already? I have similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue. 
In my case, it turned out that we had an old version of `sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\ExperienceEditor.js` file. 
After I replaced it with a new one problem solved.
Sitecore 8.2 u7